# Plotly - Generate Figures in Loop; Put all Figures in Single Subplot

Tags: python, plotly, nested-loops, subplot

I have a semi-complicated code setup so not sure how to provide an example.

That said, I have nested loops that ultimately generate a single plotly plot using `FigureFactory` from `Plotly` with `ff.create_annotated_heatmap`.  This heatmap represents a heatmap of a particular parameter I am looping through.

Ultimately, I'd like to compare all of these subplots.

So in my loop I do

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap( z, x, y, annotation_text)

Then save the figures and compare manually.

However is there a way I can make a `figure_list=[]` and then by using `figure_list.append(fig)` later cycle through them and display them on a subplot?

Answer (score 0):

- start by building 20 *annotated heat maps* in a list
- choose two to add to a **sub-plots figure** (for purpose of this example randomly)
- you can use standard technique of adding traces from figures previously created to sub-plots figure
- key with *annotated heat maps* are annotations. these are part of the layout.  Key to transferring these is to consider which x&y axis is used by the row so `xref` and `yref` can be set correctly
- for verification, `show()` is used but would not form part of code to demonstrate annotations have been correctly transferred.  In answer I have shown final output - the sub-plot

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

# fmt: off
teams = [f"Team {n}" for n in list("ABCDEFG")]
games = [f"Game {num}" for num in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']]
# fmt: on

# generate lots of annotated traces with randomized data
figs = [
    ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
        z=np.random.uniform(0, 1, [3, 3]),
        x=np.random.choice(teams, 3, replace=False).tolist(),
        y=np.random.choice(games, 3, replace=False).tolist(),
        annotation_text=np.random.choice(["Win", "Lose"], [3, 3]),
    )
    for _ in range(20)
]

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=1,
)

# randomly add two annotated heatmaps to sub-plots
for r, f in enumerate(np.random.choice(figs, 2)):
    # show plot to test that integrated plot is correct
    f.update_layout(margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0}, height=100, autosize=False).show()
    # this step is straight forward, move trace across
    fig.add_trace(f.data[0], row=r + 1, col=1)
    # now the annotations, need to override xref and yref based on target row
    for a in f.to_dict()["layout"]["annotations"]:
        fig.add_annotation(
            **{
                **a,
                **{
                    "xref": "x" if r == 0 else f"x{r+1}",
                    "yref": "y" if r == 0 else f"y{r+1}",
                },
            }
        )

# now let's view the sub-plots
fig.update_layout(margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0}, height=200, autosize=False).show()
```

[image]

#### commentary

- `fig.update_layout(margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0}, height=200, autosize=False).show()` is not part of the solution.  With any figure you can set margins https://plotly.com/python/setting-graph-size/.  l-left, r-right, t-top, b-bottom
- you stated that you want sub-plots. https://plotly.com/python/subplots/ https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html

  - start by creating a figure with sub-plots `fig = make_subplots( rows=2, cols=1, )`
  - then add traces to this sub-plotted figure.  enumerating over list of traces, knowing will add to row in sub plot that corresponds to iterator enumeration

Comment: This is great.  I understand it works but can you explain slightly what's going on? I'm having a slightly hard time converting it exactly to my setup and want to understand *why*.  In "f.update_layout(margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0}, height=100, autosize=False).show()" what is the "lrtb" for? fig.add_trace(f.data[0], row=r + 1, col=1) What is "r" value representing? Whats its limits? 

What does the ** lines mean?

Is the updated xref/yref just changing their position?

Comment: added some details to answer.  how experienced are you with python & plotly?  i.e. are you fully comfortable with enumerations and comprehensions in python?  Are you familiar that a plotly figure is made up of traces and a layout?  Traces define which axes they use and layout defines structure of axis